# What framework has been used to build scikit-learn's website

Tags: scikit-learn, documentation-generation, web-frameworks, code-documentation

[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org) is a very well organized website and is a neat way to document source code. Are the webpages automatically-generated? Is there a framework which produces these pages?

Learning which framework has been used can help me document other similar repositories that I own.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why the downvotes. Will be happy to make the question clearer/appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using [sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) and probably some extensions like [sphinx-gallery](https://github.com/sphinx-gallery/sphinx-gallery).

This is indicated [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#documentation).